# Access PDF Hosted in AWS private bucket

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3

I have a PDF in a private bucket in AWS S3 that I would like to reference on an MVC website. Basically I have code that creates the PDF and uploads it to AWS then I'd like to display that PDF in another browser tab for the end user to view. Is there a way to authenticate access to a PDF in a private AWS bucket? Or do I need to download the PDF and host it locally?

Comment: 1. Does the s3 bucket have to remain private?  2. Could you create another s3 bucket for storing PDFs? 3. Are you willing to write some code, to run in AWS, to deliver the PDFs but with limited access?

Comment: @tgolisch 1. Yes 2. No 3. I went another route. I ended up just writing the document to a local directory and hosting it that way. It's not pretty but it works. :(